# How do i connect an air compressor's 5 wires to a 3 prong 220 dryer plug?

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution

I have an air compressor that has a 110 plug with separate extra wires for optional 220 connection.

It has 5 wires showing for the 220 option:
black, white, brown, orange, and a purple wire.

-The purple wire is a larger gauge then the rest.-
-The brown and orange are capped together.-

I have a 3 pronged 220 plug w/ 10-3 wire. How do i connect the air compressor wiring(5 wires) to the 3 prong 220 dryer plug?[image]

Comment: Please make a picture of the id plate.Then we might be able to help.Did you see a capacitor somewhere?

Comment: I might  have some information for you that brings you further but are not sure yet. Here is the link,  http://www.servicetechllc.com/content/b317-marathon-12-hp-general-purpose-motor-115208-230-vac-1800-rpm-56-frame-ball-bearing-auto

Comment: Is there a wiring diagram on the motor? If so, can you post a photo of it?

Comment: It is interesting to find out how far OP came sofar. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the motor plate to see what they want you to do.

Typically with a 120/240 switchable motor, you are jumpering two sections of the motor into series or parallel.  So for 120V you might make connections hot1-A-C and B-D-neutral, and for 220V you wire hot1-A, B-C, and D-hot2.   It may be more complicated than that if there's a start capacitor or start winding involved.

Point being you must make those connections as the factory instructs, and those instructions will be particular to the motor, and should be on the motor plate.